# Php get method with the & as part of string

Tags: php, mysql, get, mysqli, special-characters

I have a typical php get method which get the name of a school from the url like this.

```
 $sname_original = $_GET['school'];
```

I then displays the name of the school like this.

```
echo $sname_original;
```

this works perfectly except if the name of the school has a '&' symbol in it. If there is an & symbol for example "Texas a&m" then the echo is displayed as "Texas a" and everything else is cut off.  Is there an escape I should be doing or what? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, you have to apply [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/urlencode) to every url parameter value, after that `&` will be encoded as `%26` and space as a `+`:

```
Texas+a%26m
```

**Inportant**: you only need to encode when generate url, and php will decode it automatically when parses the url

Comment: I'm curious. Why not preg_replace with `&amp;`?

Comment: @Fred: and how about space? Try to compose the `preg_replace` that does the same job

Comment: I thought I'd seen a similar question before.

Comment: @Fred: I'm not sure I'm following you :-(

Comment: Someone asked a similar question on SO in finding an ampersand in a string and replacing it with `&amp;` - I thought that's what Keith asked for.

Comment: @Fred: this question isn't about a simple replace of a single char, it's about a proper encoding of strings passed to the url parameter. And there is a special function for that